# How to query all model objects except the ones that already are in another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a Django application. I have 2 models relevant to the question:

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
  """
  Represents a Quiz for a `Module`.

  It will have a `name`
  """
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  user = models.ManyToManyField('cme.Bussines', related_name='quizes', through='UserQuiz', through_fields=('quiz', 'user'))

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'{self.name}'

class Trio(models.Model):
  """
  Represents the content for a Module.  

  Each `Trio` will have, as it's name says, 3 content fields, plus the
  `Module` it belongs to.

  It will have a `file`, a `video` (which will be a URL to a YT video), and a `quiz`
  (which will be key to `Quiz`)
  """
  file = models.FileField(upload_to='legacy/classes/', max_length=254)
  quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='trios', null=True, blank=True)
  video = models.URLField()
  module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trios')
  user = models.ManyToManyField('cme.Bussines', related_name='trios', through='UserTrio', through_fields=('trio', 'user'))

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'Trio {self.id} de {self.module}'
```

I want to query all the `Quiz`zes that are not in `quiz` field of `Trio`. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can query with:

```
Quiz.objects.filter(trios=None)
```

This will make a LEFT OUTER JOIN and only retain `Quiz`zes for which there is no related `Trio` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can query all `Quiz` objects whose `id` is seen in any `Trio` object :

```
Quiz.objects.exclude(id__in=Trio.objects.values("quiz_id"))
```

You can also refine the query further. For example, let's say you want all `Quiz` objects not referred by a specific **subset** of `Trio` objects, you can do so by adding a filter in your exclude expression, something like :

```
Quiz.objects.exclude(id__in=Trio.objects.filter(...).values("quiz_id"))
```

Comment: But this does the opposite: you retain all `Quiz`zes referred to by a `Trio`. Furthermore if you use for example an `.exclude(..)`, you basically trade a JOIN for a subquery with an `WHERE id IN (...)` which will, depending on the database, have other characteristics. If you want to retain `Quiz`zes where the related `Trio` holds a specific value, you filter with `Quiz.objects.filter(trios__some_field=some_value)`.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, switching those filters for excludes !

Comment: I've removed mention of avoiding joins as necessarily an advantage, I haven't actually done a performance benchmark on it. Leaving my answer up though as it's just another approach.

Comment: sure, I'm not saying that a LEFT OUTER JOIN is better, that depends on the exact database, as well as the query plan and the number of `Quiz`zes and `Trio`s. +1 :)